# how to fix this error? ? WARNING discord.gateway Shard ID None heartbeat blocked for more than 30 seconds

Tags: web-scraping, while-loop, discord, bots

I need help from someone who knows about bot discord and webscrapping. Here's my code, when I run it everything goes well at first, but then I get this error message.

I've tried setting a longer sleep and it doesn't seem to give me this error message, except that I'd need to set no delay or even remove the asyncio.sleep(0.5).

`````
async def fetch_articles(channel):
        print('Searching for new articles...')

        articles = vintedSearch(channel['url'])
        if not articles['items']:
            return

        item = articles['items'][0]
            # vérifier ID DATABASE
        c.execute('SELECT id FROM articles WHERE id = ?', (item['id'],))
        existing_item = c.fetchone()

        if existing_item is None:
            time = item['photo']['high_resolution']['timestamp']

            embed = discord.Embed(
                title=item['title'],
                url=item['url'],
                description='',
                color=0x7000FF
            )
            embed.add_field(name="**```` Prix**", value=f"`{item['price']} €`" if item.get('price') else "Aucun", inline=True)
            embed.add_field(name="**```` Taille**", value=f"`{item['size_title']}`" if item.get('size_title') else "Aucune", inline=True)
            embed.add_field(name="**```` Marque**", value=f"`{item['brand_title']}`" if item.get('brand_title') else "Aucune", inline=True)
            embed.add_field(name="**```` Auteur**", value=f"`{item['user']['login']}`" if item.get('user') and 'login' in item['user'] else "Aucune", inline=True)
            embed.add_field(name="temps", value=f'<t:{time}:R>')
            if item.get('photo') and 'url' in item['photo']:
                embed.set_image(url=item['photo']['url'])
            if item.get('photo') and 'high_resolution' in item['photo']:
                embed.set_footer(text='Edge Society', icon_url='https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1129144648196173825/1140373129009569925/logo_test_3.png')
            view = View()
            buttons = [
                Button(style=discord.ButtonStyle.success, label="❓Détails", url=item['url']),
                Button(style=discord.ButtonStyle.red, label="✅ Acheter", url='https://www.vinted.fr/checkout?transaction_id=' + str(item['id'])),
                Button(style=discord.ButtonStyle.blurple, label=" Négocier", url='https://www.vinted.fr/inbox/' + str(item['user']['id'])),
                Button(style=discord.ButtonStyle.blurple, label="AUTOBUY ( soon... )")
            ]
            for button in buttons:
                view.add_item(button)
                        
            await client.get_channel(channel["channelId"]).send(embed=embed, view=view)
                
                # RENTRER INFOS DB
            c.execute('INSERT INTO articles (id, title, url, price, size_title, brand_title, user_login, timestamp) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)',
                    (item['id'], item['title'], item['url'], item.get('price'), item.get('size_title'), item.get('brand_title'), item['user']['login'] if item.get('user') and 'login' in item['user'] else None, time))
            conn.commit()



@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged in as {client.user}!')

    async def run_channel_thread(channel):
            while b0k:
                await fetch_articles(channel)
                await asyncio.sleep(0.5)

    for channel in channels:
        asyncio.create_task(run_channel_thread(channel))
`````